# Issue with java eclipse maven (and ant) on copying jar file through ssh

Tags: java, ssh, maven-3, eclipse-indigo, maven-antrun-plugin

I have the following:

- running `eclipse-indigo` in `CentOS 6.2`,
- I also installed `apache-ant-1.8.4` in my system and set `ANT_HOME` variable to it in `eclipse`.
- In eclipse I have installed the `maven2` plug-in, that uses `maven-3.0.4` version, that is installed on my system (I configured `eclipse` to use it).

I have a maven project on my eclipse and I want every time when I `install` - (the `maven` goal) - it, the resulted `jar` file to be copied in a specific location on my server - through `ssh`. For this I did the following on my `pom.xml`:

```
   <build>
    <plugins >
            <plugin>
        <groupId > org.apache.maven.plugins </groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks name="ssh_task">
                            <taskdef name="scp" 
                                      classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp" classpathref="/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jsch.jar" />
                            <scp file="/absolute/path/to/myfile.jar" 
                                 todir="root@$10.3.1.1:/remote/location" 
                                 password="mypass" 
                                 trusted="true"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I configured my `pom.xml` in that way following this posts:

- [Maven Ant SCP error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402387/maven-ant-scp-error)
- [Maven copy local file to remote server using SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909867/maven-copy-local-file-to-remote-server-using-ssh#910047)
  and some other external links.

Now the problem is that when I run `install` goal with `eclipse` I get the following error:

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (default) on project myprojectname: An Ant BuildException has occured: Reference /usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jsch.jar not found. -> [Help 1]

The problem is that the `ant-jsch.jar` is there.

**Question**: Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with my issue? If you want to know the full stack trace just tell me.

EDIT:

```
ant -diagnostics
------- Ant diagnostics report -------
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012

-------------------------------------------
 Implementation Version
-------------------------------------------
core tasks     : 1.8.4 in file:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant.jar

-------------------------------------------
 ANT PROPERTIES
-------------------------------------------
ant.version: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
ant.java.version: 1.6
Is this the Apache Harmony VM? no
Is this the Kaffe VM? no
Is this gij/gcj? no
ant.core.lib: /usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant.jar
ant.home: /usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4

-------------------------------------------
 ANT_HOME/lib jar listing
-------------------------------------------
ant.home: /usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar (38015 bytes)
jruby-0.9.8.jar (1683526 bytes)
servlet-api-2.3.jar (77977 bytes)
serializer-2.7.1.jar (278281 bytes)
jasper-compiler-4.1.36.jar (184124 bytes)
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar (44598 bytes)
bcel-5.1.jar (515920 bytes)
xml-apis-1.3.04.jar (194354 bytes)
ant-javamail.jar (13773 bytes)
ant-commons-logging.jar (9715 bytes)
jsch-0.1.42.jar (185746 bytes)
log4j-1.2.14.jar (367444 bytes)
xalan-2.7.1.jar (3176148 bytes)
ant-jai.jar (28241 bytes)
ant-junit4.jar (12923 bytes)
ant-antlr.jar (11550 bytes)
jasper-runtime-4.1.36.jar (72397 bytes)
jai-core-1.1.3.jar (1900631 bytes)
ant-netrexx.jar (16215 bytes)
ant-junit.jar (108138 bytes)
bsh-core-2.0b4.jar (143992 bytes)
ant-jdepend.jar (14024 bytes)
asm-commons-2.2.3.jar (15114 bytes)
regexp-1.2.jar (29871 bytes)
ant.jar (1941731 bytes)
regexp-1.3.jar (25429 bytes)
commons-net-1.4.1.jar (180792 bytes)
ant-jsch.jar (46176 bytes)
asm-2.2.3.jar (34832 bytes)
bsh-2.0b4.jar (281694 bytes)
ant-apache-oro.jar (45515 bytes)
antlr-2.7.7.jar (445288 bytes)
mail-1.4.jar (388864 bytes)
ant-jmf.jar (12541 bytes)
asm-tree-2.2.3.jar (16248 bytes)
js-1.6R7.jar (813521 bytes)
activation-1.1.jar (62983 bytes)
ant-testutil.jar (21004 bytes)
ant-apache-bcel.jar (14548 bytes)
ant-swing.jar (13497 bytes)
ant-commons-net.jar (91451 bytes)
junit-4.8.1.jar (237047 bytes)
ant-apache-xalan2.jar (8097 bytes)
jdepend-2.9.1.jar (57933 bytes)
ant-apache-regexp.jar (9563 bytes)
maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar (887507 bytes)
oro-2.0.8.jar (65261 bytes)
which-1.0.jar (17398 bytes)
jai-codec-1.1.3.jar (258160 bytes)
ant-apache-resolver.jar (9886 bytes)
bsf-2.4.0.jar (113369 bytes)
NetRexxC.jar (355931 bytes)
ant-launcher.jar (18429 bytes)
ant-apache-log4j.jar (8861 bytes)
ant-apache-bsf.jar (9733 bytes)
xml-resolver-1.2.jar (84091 bytes)

-------------------------------------------
 USER_HOME/.ant/lib jar listing
-------------------------------------------
user.home: /root
No such directory.

-------------------------------------------
 Tasks availability
-------------------------------------------
All defined tasks are available

-------------------------------------------
 org.apache.env.Which diagnostics
-------------------------------------------
#---- BEGIN: Which report
Which.version=Which.java:($Revision: 1.2 $) WhichJar.java:($Revision: 1.2 $)
java.version=1.6.0_31
file.encoding=UTF-8
java.ext.dirs=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
java.class.path=/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jruby-0.9.8.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/servlet-api-2.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/serializer-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jasper-compiler-4.1.36.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/bcel-5.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jai.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jasper-runtime-4.1.36.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jai-core-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/bsh-core-2.0b4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/asm-commons-2.2.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/regexp-1.2.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/regexp-1.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/asm-2.2.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/mail-1.4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/asm-tree-2.2.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/js-1.6R7.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-swing.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/junit-4.8.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jdepend-2.9.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/which-1.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jai-codec-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/bsf-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/NetRexxC.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/xml-resolver-1.2.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/lib/tools.jar
os.name=Linux
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
sun.boot.class.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/classes
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
#----   END: Which report

-------------------------------------------
 XML Parser information
-------------------------------------------
XML Parser : com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl
XML Parser Location: unknown
Namespace-aware parser : com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Namespace-aware parser Location: unknown

-------------------------------------------
 XSLT Processor information
-------------------------------------------
XSLT Processor : org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl
XSLT Processor Location: file:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar

-------------------------------------------
 System properties
-------------------------------------------
java.runtime.name : Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path : /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/i386
java.vm.version : 20.6-b01
ant.library.dir : /usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib
java.vm.vendor : Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vendor.url : http://java.sun.com/
path.separator : :
java.vm.name : Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM
file.encoding.pkg : sun.io
user.country : US
sun.java.launcher : SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level : unknown
java.vm.specification.name : Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir : /home/artaxerxe
java.runtime.version : 1.6.0_31-b04
java.awt.graphicsenv : sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs : /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/endorsed
os.arch : i386
java.io.tmpdir : /tmp
line.separator : 

java.vm.specification.vendor : Sun Microsystems Inc.
os.name : Linux
ant.home : /usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4
sun.jnu.encoding : UTF-8
java.library.path : /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/i386:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
java.specification.name : Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version : 50.0
sun.management.compiler : HotSpot Tiered Compilers
os.version : 2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.i686
user.home : /root
user.timezone : Europe/Bucharest
java.awt.printerjob : sun.print.PSPrinterJob
file.encoding : UTF-8
java.specification.version : 1.6
user.name : root
java.class.path : /usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jruby-0.9.8.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/servlet-api-2.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/serializer-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jasper-compiler-4.1.36.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/bcel-5.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jai.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jasper-runtime-4.1.36.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jai-core-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/bsh-core-2.0b4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/asm-commons-2.2.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/regexp-1.2.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/regexp-1.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/asm-2.2.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/mail-1.4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/asm-tree-2.2.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/js-1.6R7.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-swing.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/junit-4.8.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jdepend-2.9.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/which-1.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jai-codec-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/bsf-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/NetRexxC.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/xml-resolver-1.2.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/lib/tools.jar
java.vm.specification.version : 1.0
sun.arch.data.model : 32
java.home : /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre
sun.java.command : org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp  -diagnostics
java.specification.vendor : Sun Microsystems Inc.
user.language : en
java.vm.info : mixed mode
java.version : 1.6.0_31
java.ext.dirs : /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
sun.boot.class.path : /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/classes
java.vendor : Sun Microsystems Inc.
file.separator : /
java.vendor.url.bug : http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi
sun.cpu.endian : little
sun.io.unicode.encoding : UnicodeLittle
sun.desktop : gnome
sun.cpu.isalist : 

-------------------------------------------
 Temp dir
-------------------------------------------
Temp dir is /tmp
Temp dir is writeable
Temp dir alignment with system clock is -731 ms

-------------------------------------------
 Locale information
-------------------------------------------
Timezone Eastern European Time offset=10800000

-------------------------------------------
 Proxy information
-------------------------------------------
Java1.5+ proxy settings:
Direct connection
```

Comment: can you provide the output of ant -diagnostics, thanks.

Comment: @hovanessyan : can you help me houw to get this? I'm very new to `ant`.

Comment: If you have ant configured correctly (it's in the $PATH and all) you should be able to execute the command 'ant -diagnostics' in a terminal/console. How did you install Ant? from a distribution package or from the zip archive?

Comment: @hovanessyan from the zip archive. I followed step by step the Ant User guide for this.| I put the output on the answer.

Comment: the jsch is actually in your java classpath...

Comment: the only thing I can think of now is to replace your jsch-0.1.42.jar with the current version jsch-0.1.48.jar. You can download it from here http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`classpathref` is used to define a reference to a previously defined property.

You should try to define your classpath variable:

```
<path id="jsch-classpath">
        <fileset dir="/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/" includes="ant-jsch.jar"/>
</path>
```

and then use it in the task:

```
<taskdef name="scp" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp" classpathref="jsch-classpath" />
```

Comment: You need to modify the `jsch-classpath` definition. The simplest way is to state`includes="*.jar"` but take a look at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html if you need to define a more exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The install phase of Maven is intended to install artifacts into the local repository and not intended to transfer files to a remote server. If you are trying to deploy and artifact into a Tomcat/JBoss whatever it's better to take a look at the [cargo2-maven-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) or the [tomcat-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html) which are intended to deploy artifact to servers.

Furhtermore i would recommend the [maven-wagon-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html) to upload an artifact to a server instead of using Ant in this case which would make life easier.

Comment: I don't want to deploy an artifact. I only want to do what I suggested: to copy my jar in a place on my server, where a running application will be able to load that jar at runtime.